# Date missing in dataset

Tags: sas

I created below SAS code to pull the data for particular a date.

```
%let date =2016-12-31;


proc sql;
connect to teradata   as tera ( user=testuser password=testpass );
create table new as select * from connection tera (select acct,org 
from dw.act
where date= &date.);
disconnect from tera;
quit;
```

There are situation where that particular date may be missing in the dataset due to holiday.

I thinking how to query the previous date(non-holiday) if the mention date in the %let statement is holiday

Comment: can you paste the error output/log to help us better understand.

Comment: I am not sure. How to query the previous date if the mention date is not available

Answer (score 1):

Before running your query you have to do a lookup or data check on the date you are using. You have two options:

1. Use a Date Dimension table in order identify/lookup holidays.
2. Count how many records you have for that date, if you get 0 obs for this date, use date+1 in your query.

I recommend using the date dimension table option.

Answer (score 1):

Teradata has Sys_Calendar.Calendar view. You can use that in query, it has all the information regarding weekdays and others.

if you want to SAS way use weekday function and use call symput as shown below. Teradata needs single quote around the date, so it is better to have single quotes around when creating macro variable

```
  data _null_;
  /* this is for intial date*/
   date_int = input('2016-12-31', yymmdd10.);
 /* create a new date variable depending on weekday*/
  if weekday(date_int) = 7 then date =date_int-2; /*sunday -2 days to get 
  friday*/
  else if weekday(date_int) = 6 then date =date_int-1;/*saturday -1 day to get 
   friday*/
  else date =date_int;
  format date  date_int yymmdd10.;
  call symputx('date', ''''||put(date,yymmdd10.)||'''');
  run;
  %put modfied date is &date;
  modified date is '2016-12-29'
```

Now you can use this macro variable in your pass through.